# replace the first word of a javascript string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In the string

> somethingcryptic12A@#$~` abc def@#

, I would like to replace the first word by new so that it would then be new

> new abc def@#

. How can I do this using regular expression. I have made the first word cryptic to indicate that it can contain any character and any number of characters. It's the first word if there is a space after it.

Comment: In my defense, I was able to come up with the full solution after some initial help from Some1. I had tried some solutions like [a-zA-Z] but that wouldn't work for all scenarios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this regular expression

```
^\S+
```

`^` represents start of the string

`\S` matches any character **except** space..

`+` matches preceding character 1 to many times

Comment: correct solution is var newvalue = original.replace(/^\S+/g, 'new');

Comment: `\S` matches anything other than "whitespace characters", which is equivalent to `[^ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​\u2028\u2029​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]` in character class notation.

Comment: thanks Vishal - you should post your solution as an answer and I'll upvote it. You saved me five minutes. ta